# VSTS Online - Copy files from AGENT MACHINE to VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I use the VSTS online build and release process. I have two servers that have firewalls between them (can't just run a script on Server1 to accomplish moving a file between servers). I have installed the VSTS Agent on both servers and each server is assigned to its own Pool in VSTS. I can release to either server with out any issues.

What I can't figure out (or if its even possible) is how can I copy files FROM an agent in one pool to VSTS' release working directory/temp path (or even better from one pool, directly to another agent pool)?

For example, I have a Server1 in Pool1 and Server2 in Pool2. For my release steps, I have selected "Run on agent" and selected Pool1. I then have a task that copies files over to the agent and it does its thing. What I need to do is then pull down a zip file from a path accessible by the Pool1 server(s) to VSTS and send that zip file to a path accisble by the Pool2 server(s).

Is it possible to download a file from an agent pool? I assume if I was able to have the "run on pool1 steps" store that zip file somewhere in the release temp path/working dir, I would be able to do a windows file copy to send it from the working directory to the "run on pool2 steps".

Answer (score 1):

- If the other machine can be accessed by Windows Machine File Copy task. You can use [**Windows Machine File Copy task**](https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-cn/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) to copy files from a machine to another. Settings for the task as below:

  **Source:** path for the files you want to copy, such as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/drop`.

  **Machines:** IP of the other machine you want to copy to.

  **Admin Login:** `ComputerName\AdminUserName`.

  **Password:** password for Admin user name.

  **Destination Folder:** path for the other machine you want to copy files to.
- If you still can't access the other machine based on firewall settings, you can upload the files to a place where both the two machines can access (such as your own website or github etc), and then use a power shell tash to download files from website.

Comment: Thanks but this copies from VSTS to the AGENT ... I am looking to do the opposite, run a command on the AGENT that produces a zip file like c:\archive.zip, then copy the zip file to VSTS, then have another "Run on agent task" (and could use windows machine file copy) to copy that zip from VSTS to another Agent pool set of servers

Comment: Directly use windows machine file copy can copy files from a machine to the other. If you want to copy zip file, you can add a Archive files task before windows machine file copy task. If you want to upload files to VSTS firstly and then download with the other agent, you can  add powershell task to commit/push/clone for a VSTS git repo.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT: How can we upload the files to GitHub? Can you please help me to find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn’t the task to download the file from an agent to other, also the middle server is needed if these servers can’t connect to each others to upload/download files (e.g. FTP, HTTP)

On the other hand, the files aren’t stored in agent pool, they are in agent, the agent pool is used to organize agents and different servers/agents can in the same agent pool, also a server can in multiple agent pools. [Agent pools and queues](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/pools-queues).

Comment: What about downloading from the AGENT to VSTS? For example, I run a powershell script that archives the destination folder that the release files are going to. It would be nice to download that archive and store it with the release artifacts used for the release (i.e. for roll back / release accidentally deletes files you didn't think it would delete, etc)

Comment: @Vee The artifacts can't be associated to release (Throw exception for Publish artifacts task in release), you can copy the necessary files to a shared folder or upload to a FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are going to make a very brittle spaghetti type build. These files that are needed can they not be held in source control or as an artifact of a build? That way you can clone/pull the repo or just use the download artifact task that is out in preview now.